# google calendar api reminder

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to access the reminder calendar in the my calendar account with the google calendar API. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation. When I request a list of my calendars, it gives me every calendar in my calendar account, apart from the reminder calendar.

I want some way to add a reminder using the Google calendar API.

Comment: No way to do that right now.

Comment: Add your star to the [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4437&can=1&sort=-stars&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner).

Comment: To anyone: as written by @aaron-alphonsus, do **star** the ['Add an API for Reminders'](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283) issue on Google issue tracker! This will put some highlight / pressure on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use your calendar ID to reference that calendar.

1. Go to google calendars
2. Go to calendar settings for the calendar you are trying to reference
3. scroll to the bottom and find where it says Calendar Address: across from that is your calendar ID. Use that in your query. for example in swift to get events from a calendar use this

   ```
   let query = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsList.query(withCalendarId:  "insert your calendar ID here")
   query.maxResults = 10
   query.timeMin = GTLRDateTime(date: Date())
   query.singleEvents = true
   query.orderBy = kGTLRCalendarOrderByStartTime

   service.executeQuery(
       query,
       delegate: self,
       didFinish:         #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
   ```